# Sql query to find out no of boys and girls in school

Tags: sql, rdbms

Sql query to find out no of boys and girls in school

is it correct

```
select count(*)
from schooldata
group by sex;
```

Comment: Did you try running it?

Comment: Is OP taking a test on SQL right now or something? 2nd question that just asks "is it correct"

Comment: This seems to be a very popular homework assignment.

Answer (score 3):

You need sex in select as well, otherwise you can't tell which is which.

```
select sex, count(*) from schooldata group by sex;
```